# Estimation of Large Seemingly Unrelated Regressions Systems

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, matrix

I'm using Bayesian methods to estimate a system of [Seemingly Unrelated Regressions (SUR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seemingly_unrelated_regressions). The system I'm estimating, however, is large, and I'm trying to find a computationally feasible way to implement the estimation.

Continuing the notation of the linked Wikipedia article, suppose m is very large, potentially hundreds of equations. The number of regressors per equation is generally between 8 and 20. In the kth step of the Gibbs sampling, the algorithm provides a draw for Sigma, the covariance matrix of residuals (corresponding to the first step in the FGLS stage). In the second step, however, I'm having to solve a system of matrix equations for the coefficient vector. These matrices are obviously very large.

In R, I've used some of the classes from the Matrix package effectively to manage memory with some of these computations, but currently, the time required to calculate the coefficient vector and its covariance matrix are infeasible for my current application. Here is some sample code:

```
library(Matrix)

X0 = bdiag(lapply(equations, get.regressors, regressors = z))
sandwich.term = kronecker(chol2inv(chol(Sigma)), Diagonal(obs))
X0t.O.X0 = t(X0) %*% sandwich.term %*% X0
beta.hat = qr.solve(X0t.O.X0, t(X0) %*% sandwich.term %*% c(y))
cov.beta = chol2inv(chol(X0t.O.X0))
```

The `get.regressors` function selects from the data the values of the matrix Xi for the ith regression.

Any suggestions for increasing the performance here would be tremendously appreciated! Or, if you believe this is just a problem of dimensionality, please let me know.

Comment: Questions about how to use R code are off topic here. This might fly on [SO]. If you wait, we will migrate it for you.

Comment: That would be great, thanks.

Comment: After doing some searching, I came upon the [vignette for the `systemfit` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/systemfit/index.html). On page 15, the authors show the method they've found most efficient for GLS estimations. I've replicated their suggestion and found that it does provide a performance boost, but it still isn't fast enough to include in my MCMC analysis (y series > 200, observations > 300, at most 20 regressors). Not to mention I still have to invert a large matrix to find the covariance matrix of the coefficients.

Comment: Hey Alex, I am interested in implementing a Bayesian SUR model as well! Would you happen to have any code to share? I was thinking about parallelizing it with pymc3.

Comment: @rprog, I decided to abandon this project in R and ended up using BLAS libraries and C to perform my calculations. I'm still working to finish it, however.